# Trying to retain a single data label from each kind from a list of many

Tags: python, numpy, unique

This is part of the code im trying to use. The program iterates through many files and I   need it to capture just one roadway corridor name for each roadway. Each file has thousands of lines and I just want it to output one corridor name from each.

Each corridor name looks C0XXXXX like but of course there are many variations like C000044, C000256, C000422 on and on:

Im new to grabbing unique values but here is the code

```
    def parser_rut_data(setter):
        import numpy as np
        for col in setter.parse_list[0:]:
            route = col[6]            
        yield np.unique(route)
```

And here is the output where the inputed corridors were C000001:

```
['0' '1' 'C']
['0' '1' 'C']
['0' '1' 'C']
['0' '1' 'C']
```

Here is a short example of the input data, its a text file:

```
08/25/2014,C000010,ASC,I,1,0.0,0.1,0.1,0.14,0.04,0.39,0.22,211,160,186,47,29.663843,-111,-16.907026,3433,0,26.5,12:5
```

Comment: Example of input data or file?

Comment: 08/25/2014,C000010,ASC,I,1,     0.0,     0.1, 0.1,0.14,0.04,0.39,0.22,211,160,186,47,29.663843,-111,-16.907026,3433,0,26.5,12:5

Comment: what exactly do you want to get from the line of input you posted, also what is `setter.parse_list[0:]` doing?

Comment: Not entirely sure what _roadway corridor name_ is. Is the input example you gave a single line that you need to output since it contains a C0XXXXX entry? This seems like a job for [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). If you need just to output a single entry from each file, just break the parsing loop when you've found the first one. Did I understand you correctly? Also, `parse_list[0:]` is the same as the entire list i.e. `parse_list`.

Comment: Ok well the setter.parse_list is calling to a list that was appended to in the class setter in another file. The top of this file has the import script. So setter is the class and parse_list is the list. The list comprehension [0:] is just a habit of mine i guess. Roadway corridor name is the way we categorize sections of roadway. For the most part is correlates with highways lengths but multiple highways can be part of a larger corridor. So C000044 is corridor 44. I hope that helps.

Comment: Ultimately what i would like to do is list each corridor then behind each corridor list the dates the roadway condition data was collected. This saves me lots of mindless spreadsheet work. So within each line of data there is a corridor, like C0000044 and a date. For each corridor I would like the date that corresponds to it. I know this is a little esoteric, and I try to keep the amount of code a post to a minimum.

Answer (score -1):

Does that work for you? This doesn't use numpy and only extacts your C0XXXXX code.

```
import re
s = re.compile("C[0-9]+")
ll = []
with open("myfile") as f1:

    for line in f1:

         temp = s.search(line);

         if temp:
            ll.append(temp.group())
```

You haven't given us any indication to what you really want to do with the code once it's extracted. But if my interpretation is correct, you seem to be printing out all the "Unique" numbers from the retrieved code. In that case;

```
ss = sorted(set(ll))
```

This gives you the unique corridor numbers in list.

Comment: I like the look of that thanks! But I'm home now so I can't try out the code but ill try it tomorrow morning for sure and let you know.

Comment: @hollow_Victory     It's not about voting down. Because you pasted 4 rows of `['0' '1' 'C']` one after another, I couldn't understand if you wanted 1 set of unique corridor each time you enter file or something else.

Comment: I'd store the result of `s.search` to avoid searching twice. Also if you want unique values, use `set.add` instead of appending to a list. Also the regex will also match stuff like C982342 without the leading zero. If there indeed is a leading zero and the code is guaranteed to be have 5 varying digits, I'd rather be explicit: `s = re.compile('C0\d{5}$')`

Comment: Well the ['0' '1' 'C'] i posted was just a sample of the output. I understand if if didnt seem too informative.

Comment: @hollow_Victory      so does this solution do what you wanted or you want it to work for a set of similar files?